# Are there any statistics for the demographics of the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, statistics

Since there are thousands of species across the Star Wars universe, is there any statistic (fan-made or canon) about its demographics (per system/planet/globally)?

Comment: [Galactic population can be found here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76427/68872), most common species [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86878/68872). Otherwise there doesn't seem to be a particular amount to go on. Maybe you could consider fleshing out your question a bit to provide some more context as to why you're seeking an answer to this question and what may help in answering your question.

Comment: In order to start a SW RPG campaign I would like to know if humans were the most important race amongst any other.  So this link https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85602/what-is-the-most-widespread-numerous-alien-species-in-star-wars-other-than-huma/86878#86878[/link] was really useful

Comment: Judging by the movies, mostly British and American men, a couple of them in costumes. Not a fan, but if you consider fan made, I can be a fan